# Local storage sharing between WKWebviews

Tags: ios, local-storage, wkwebview

I need to share the data when navigating from a WKWebView in one View Controller to a new one which also has contains a WKWebView. Technically we are implementing native navigation with using webviews. For the second WKWebView to load correctly we need the cookies and the parameters saved in the local storage by the first one.

Tried sharing the same websiteDataStore and the same process pool between the webviews. What's interesting here is that the cookies are transferred properly - we get a logged in session on the second webview, however the localStorage is not. We could see that the local storage data is present in the first webview through the Safari WKWebView debugger, and the second webview has empty local storage.

Here is the code we use for setting up the webview. If we print the data records of the website data store it would print cookies, localStorage and sessionStorage, but it seems just the cookies get transferred..

Any ideas why this doesn't work or how the localStorage could be shared between the webviews?

```
- (void)setupWebView
 {
     WKWebViewConfiguration *webViewConfiguration = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];
     webViewConfiguration.websiteDataStore = MBAbstractWebViewController.sharedWebsiteDataStore;
    [MBAbstractWebViewController.sharedWebsiteDataStore fetchDataRecordsOfTypes:WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes
                                                              completionHandler:^(NSArray<WKWebsiteDataRecord *> *records) {

        NSLog(@"%@", records);
    }];
    webViewConfiguration.processPool = MBAbstractWebViewController.sharedProcessPool;
    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                  configuration:webViewConfiguration];
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately no, what we did as a workaround we pass the whole wkwebview by reference to the next view controller. There we attach it to the view. Then when we need to navigate back we again attach it to the previous view controller's view and change the delegate for handling the events. So, technically we ended up using only one WKWebView instance in both view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on iOS 15.5 and was able to share localStorage between two WKWebViews without doing anything special. I simply created two WKWebViews with the following code and added them to two ViewControllers.

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
```

However, I could not share localStorage between applications with different Bundle Identifiers.

I want to share localStorage between the main application and the extension in an app with an ActionExtension, but I have not found a way to do that.